# MVVM using RxJava in the proper way

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I am trying to use MVVM in my new Android project. Also, I am using RxJava for this purpose. I am using Kotlin. I have gone through many docs, post, and tutorials for the same. I did a sample app trying out stuff.

ACTIVITY

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var vehicleInVM: VehicleInVM? = null
    var disposable: CompositeDisposable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        vehicleInVM = VehicleInVM()
        disposable = CompositeDisposable()


        vehicleInVM?.checkVehicleNumberPlate("111")?.subscribe({ t1: Boolean?, t2: Throwable? ->
            Logger.getLogger("GP").severe("$t1")
        })?.let { disposable!!.add(it) }


    }
}
```

VIEW MODEL

```
class VehicleInVM {

    var capacity: Capacity?=null

    init {
        capacity= Capacity()
    }


    fun checkVehicleNumberPlate(string: String?): Single<Boolean>? {
        if (string == null) {
            return Single.create<Boolean> { emitter ->
                emitter.onSuccess(false)
            }
        }
        val regex = Constants.VEHICL_NUMBER_REGEX
        return Single.create<Boolean> { emitter ->
            emitter.onSuccess(string?.let { regex.matches(it) })
        }
    }



    fun getVehicleCapacity(type:String): Observable<String>? {

        return capacity?.getCapacity(type)
    }

}
```

Is what I am doing the correct way to implement MVVM?

Comment: You're just using RxJava, but since you don't use any sort of binding between the VM and the View (you don't even show us the view), it's not MVVM (you're only logging the boolean result)  
You should also change the inner state of the VM and somehow notify the the View about that (e.g. via Databinding) so that it can update itself.

So the answer is **no**. You're not using MVVM.

Comment: so is it compulsory for me to use data binding in MVVM?

Comment: you can also use your own mechanism, but Databinding is the easiest. The reason is, that the ViewModel should _not_ know about the View, and the Model should _not_ know the ViewModel.
[Here is an example I found](https://github.com/kaskasi/VocabularyTrainer) it's not perfect, since its using a lot of `doOn` methods for manipulating the VM's state, but it's a start.

Comment: @Lovis thanks, sir. But the checkVehicleNumberPlate() function only does the logical thing nothing abt updating the UI

Comment: exactly. but without a View, I can't tell whether you're using MVVM correctly, since the first V stands for View ;-)